# how do i make three attempts in my quiz in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My question is how can I add to my game quiz so that each question has 3 attempts, the first attempt is text only, for example "which operating system is the most represented?" and below 4 answers to choose from, if the answer is not correct, then the next attempt goes, again the text of the question but this time a picture pops up, for example a mobile phone, and the 4 answers is given again, if it is incorrect again then a text with a picture containing the sound of a mobile phone pops up again , (or video clip) if the answer is incorrect even then, the next question continues and 0 points are awarded for this. I also have points in my quiz and I need to make the first attempt have 30 points, the second attempt 15, the third attempt 5, and if the answer is not correct at all, then 0 and it continues. I have a project on my GitHub account, the name is Nino94Unity, the name of the scene that needs to be opened is "Biologija", and it is in the folder "MojKviz", the only problem is that it is in the Serbian language, but again I think that when you see visually it will be easier than I explain to you.

I expect that someone will be able to help me because I cannot finish my graduate thesis without that supplement.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly you just need a collection of `QuestionHints` with data inside, a method to display it and variable to track what hint level is now. The initial question text could be just one of the hints at index `0` for the sake of modularity. Pseudo code below:

```
class Question
{
    QuestionView view;
    QuestionHint[] hintLevels;
    int currentHintLevel = 0;
    void DisplayQuest()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= informationLevels; i++)
        {
            hintLevels[0].Reveal(view);
        }
    }
    void IncreaseHintLevel() => currentHintLevel ++;
}

class QuestionHint
{
    // put your text or image in this class, or may use abstract class and derive from it
    // like QuestionTextHint and QuestionImageHint
    void Reveal(QuestionView view)
    {
        //this method passes whatever info it have to quest view object to display
    }
}
```